# Why does this JavaScript if statement not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to change the value of `<input type = "hidden" name = "hidden" id = "hidden" value = "0">` whenever you select one of the drop down options from the `<select>` tag. All the code work until I get to the if statements. Please help me and thank you. This is my code below. I don't know if you need the CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 /* Hide these items on load. */
 $("nav").hide();
 $("#hrNavLines2").hide();
 $("#usersBar").hide();
 $("#videosBar").hide();
 $("#albumsBar").hide();
 var video = document.getElementById("mainVideo");
 
 $("#hrNavLines1").click(function(){
  $("#hrNavLines1").hide();
  $("#hrNavLines2").show();
  $("nav").show();
 });
 
 $("#hrNavLines2").click(function(){
  $("#hrNavLines2").hide();
  $("#hrNavLines1").show();
  $("nav").hide();
 });
 
 var opts = document.getElementById("opts");
 opts.onchange = function() {
  var selected = opts.options[opts.selectedIndex].value;

  switch(selected) {
   case "All":
    $("#allBar").show();
    $("#usersBar").hide();
    $("#videosBar").hide();
    $("#albumsBar").hide();
    break;
   case "Users":
    $("#allBar").hide();
    $("#usersBar").show();
    $("#videosBar").hide();
    $("#albumsBar").hide();
    break;
   case "Videos":
    $("#allBar").hide();
    $("#usersBar").hide();
    $("#videosBar").show();
    $("#albumsBar").hide();
    break;
   case "Albums":
    $("#allBar").hide();
    $("#usersBar").hide();
    $("#videosBar").hide();
    $("#albumsBar").show();
  }
  
  if (!$("#usersBar").is(":visible") && !$("#videosBar").is(":visible") && !$("#albumsBar").is(":visible")) {
   $("#hidden").value(0);
  } else if (!$("#allBar").is(":visible") && !$("#videosBar").is(":visible") && !$("#albumsBar").is(":visible")) {
   $("#hidden").value(1);
  } else if (!$("#allBar").is(":visible") && !$("#usersBar").is(":visible") && !$("#albumsBar").is(":visible")) {
   $("#hidden").value(2);
  } else {
   $("#hidden").value(3);
  }
  var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden");
  alert(hidden);
 }
 
});
```

```css
header > #headerTop > #title {
 font-size: 33px;
 font-family: Arial;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 6.5%;
 padding-left: 7px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}

header {
 background-color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 98.9%;
 height: 7%;
 border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
}

header a {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

nav {
 position: absolute;
 top: 93%;
 left: 0%;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom: 1.5px solid black;
 border-right: 1.5px solid black;
}

a {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#hrNavLines1, #hrNavLines2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5%;
 left: .5%;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 25px;
}

#search {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 right: 1.75%;
}

.searchBar {
 text-align: center;
 width: 680px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 margin: 0px 3px;
 font-size: 17px;
}

select {
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin: 0px 3px;
}

#searchBttn {
 height: 38px;
 width: 80px;
 font-size: 17px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 3px;
}

body {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<?PHP
 require("searchResults.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang = "en">
 <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <meta name = "description" content = "Videopia is a video websites upload your videos to be cool.">
  <meta name = "author" content = "Adam Oates">
  <meta name = "title" content = "Home">
  <title title = "Home | Videopia">
   Home | Videopia
  </title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div id = "hrNavLines1">
    <hr class = "hrNav" noshade>
    <hr class = "hrNav" noshade>
    <hr class = "hrNav" noshade>
   </div>
   <div id = "hrNavLines2">
    <hr class = "hrNav" noshade>
    <hr class = "hrNav" noshade>
    <hr class = "hrNav" noshade>
   </div>
   <nav>
    <a href = "http://videopia.gigaboywebdesigns.com/" id = "currentLink">Home</a><br><br>
    <a href = "http://videopia.gigaboywebdesigns.com/account/">Create New User</a><br><br>
   </nav>
   <div id = "headerTop">
    <span id = "title">
     Videopia
    </span>
    <span id = "search">
     <select id = "opts">
      <option id = "allOpt" value = "All">All</option>
      <option id = "usersOpt" value = "Users">Users</option>
      <option id = "videosOpt" value = "Videos">Videos</option>
      <option id = "albumsOpt" value = "Albums">Albums</option>
     </select>
     <input type = "hidden" value = "0" id = "hidden" name = "hidden">
     <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search Users, Videos, and Albums" class = "searchBar" name = "searchBar" id = "allBar">
     <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search Users" class = "searchBar" name = "usersBar" id = "usersBar">
     <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search Videos" class = "searchBar" name = "videosBar" id = "videosBar">
     <input type = "text" placeholder = "Search Albums" class = "searchBar" name = "albumsBar" id = "albumsBar">
     <input type = "button" value = "Search" id = "searchBttn" name = "searchBttn">
    </span>
   </div>
  </header>
  
  <section id = "mainIndex">
   
  </section>
  
  <footer>
   Copyright &copy; 2015 Videopia. All rights reserved.<br>
   Developed by <a href = "http://www.gigaboywebdesigns.com/">Gigaboy Web Designs</a>
  </footer>
 </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `.value()` is not jQuery method use `.val()` ; also add break; in last switch case

Comment: *"All the code work until I get to the if statements"* - and then what happens? Do you get an error in your browser's JS debug console? *"I don't know if you need the CSS."* - No.

Answer (score 2):

Change this section of your code and add a break to the last case. :

> var selected = opts.options[opts.selectedIndex].val();

Instead of :

> var selected = opts.options[opts.selectedIndex].value;

---

**Snippet :**

```
var selected = opts.options[opts.selectedIndex].val();
switch(selected) {
                case "All":
                    $("#allBar").show();
                    $("#usersBar").hide();
                    $("#videosBar").hide();
                    $("#albumsBar").hide();
                    break;
                case "Users":
                    $("#allBar").hide();
                    $("#usersBar").show();
                    $("#videosBar").hide();
                    $("#albumsBar").hide();
                    break;
                case "Videos":
                    $("#allBar").hide();
                    $("#usersBar").hide();
                    $("#videosBar").show();
                    $("#albumsBar").hide();
                    break;
                case "Albums":
                    $("#allBar").hide();
                    $("#usersBar").hide();
                    $("#videosBar").hide();
                    $("#albumsBar").show();
                    break;
```

Comment: That won't work. You're now trying to call `.val()` on a non-jquery object. `.value` as a property (not a method) works there. The error in the OP's code is later where it tries to call `.value()` as a method.